# Linked list(insert at head)

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
List<T>::~List()
{                
   ListItem<T> *temp,*temp1;
   temp=head;         
   while (temp->next!=NULL)         
   {
          temp1=temp;
          temp=temp->next;
          delete [] temp1;
   }        
}

/* This class just holds a single data item. */ 
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
vector<string> words;
T value;
ListItem<T> *next;
ListItem<T> *prev;

ListItem(T theVal)
{
    this->value = theVal;
    this->next = NULL;
    this->prev = NULL;
}
};

template <class T>
void List<T>::insertAtHead(T item)
{
 ListItem<T> *node=new ListItem<T>(item);
 if (head==NULL)
 {
     head=node;
 }
 else
 {
     node->next=head;
     head->prev=node;
     head=node;
 }           
}
int main()
{
List<int> Mylist;
for (int i=20;i>0;--i)
{
    Mylist.insertSorted(i);
}
cout<<Mylist.getTail()->value<<endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

I am making a linked list using classes and template.When I run this code,it runs fine but when i press a key to exit,the following error appears:"main.exe has stopped working"
I am using Dev c++.I have added the destructor code.I don't see any problem in it.

Comment: Than this has nothing to do with your linked list, and everything to do with `system("PAUSE");`

Comment: I removed system("PAUSE") but still i am getting the same error

Comment: You probably have a problem during destruction of `MyList`. Run in the debugger to see where it crashes. (BTW: why did you include the code for `insertAtHead`, which you don't use?)

Comment: I have added the destructor code.Please can you see if there is any problem

Comment: `delete []` should be used for memory allocated with `new []` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always pair `new` with `delete` and `new[]` with `delete[]`, but you have a mismatch

```
ListItem<T> *node=new ListItem<T>(item);
//                ^^^

delete [] temp1;
//^^^^^^^
```